# Any tool to easily record audio from movies?

Tags: audio-recording, windows

Is there any tool that I can use to record audio to mp3 when I watch movies on my computer easily .

I know some software but I need some software which work in the background so I can simply use some hot key to trigger recording and stop and export the file to disk and auto-naming the file.

So I can record multiply audio clips along watching the movie with minimum effort.

Comment: Windows XP would be the best.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how do you actually execute this if you're NOT using Windows:

Steps:

1. Enable Stereo Mix. [Use this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/)
2. Get Audacity
3. You're gonna have to [setup up stereo mix.](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer#Windows)
4. Don't forget to arm the track by clicking on the record button on the specific track.
5. Hit the big record button on the top to record the sound.

That's the cheapest solution for windows. 
The setup up stereo mix link has a few other instructions for Mac and Linux users.

Answer (score 1):

Use VB Cable.

I had the same issue, and could not seem to get my audio apps to record what I'm hearing in windows. This driver installs a new input/output which you can use to capture the audio playing.

https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/

Works like a charm!

If you want to hear what you are recording in windows through your speakers, set 'Listen to this device' by right clicking on the new output channel created in your Sound > Recording window and checking 'Listen to this device', then in the drop down select your output/speakers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac you can use an audio routing application like Soundflower with Garageband.

1. Install Soundflower: http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower
2. System preferences -> Sound, then set Output to Soundflower (2ch)
3. Open Garageband, create a new "Real instrument" track. (⌘ + ⌥ + n)
4. Garageband -> Preferences -> Audio/Midi, then set Audio Input to Soundflower (2ch) and Audio Output to Built-in Output
5. Record! Just press the R key.

If you want to listen to what you are recording:

1. Track -> Show monitoring for Real Instrument Tracks
2. Click the monitor icon on your track

Comment: The Question has the Windows tag, and a comment from the OP mentioning Windows XP, so this doesn't provide an answer.